# How do i pass query values to a new page in Framework 7

Tags: html-framework-7

I have data returned from an api call in **Framework7** - material/Android - im looping it using the prototype 'each' function so far so good ...

```
    alldata.awards.forEach(function ( item ) {
            var linkToDetails = '<a href="detail.html?rec='+item+'&ctg='+item.catgicon+'" class="button button-fill"><b>VIEW RECORD</b></a>'
    }

    var detailpg = myapp.onPageInit('detail', function ( page ) 
    {       
        $$('#results-card .facebook-avatar img').prop('src', page.query.ctg);
                $$('#results-card .facebook-bname').html(page.query.rec.businessName);      

    }).trigger();
```

According to the F7 docs we can access the query string through the 'page' object in the called method, thus: page.query.QueryKey

'page.query.ctg' outputs the 'ctg' query value ok, but since 'rec' holds a complete object i can't seem to access the property values. When i console,log it - get [object object] - no matter what i try i cant get to the data within the object. Here's what i tried:

```
* console.log( page.query.rec.BusinessName )        // outputs nothing
* console.log( page.query.rec['BusinessName'] )     // outputs nothing
* console.log( page.query.rec[0]['BusinessName'] )  // outputs nothing
* console.log( page.query.rec )                     // outputs [object object]
* console.log( page.query.rec[0] )                  // outputs [
* console.log( JSON.stringify(page.query.rec) )     // outputs "[object object]"
```

I'm stumped - i could pass each property as individual query string values but there are almost 40 items in the object so it inconvenient and poor practice.
is it a Framework7 specific issue? or am i doing this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `page.query.ctg` is the id of the object.

One of the ways is to pass the `ctg` value to the next page and then fetch the remaining data of the object from the database. You could leverage on the `.onPageInit` to call a fetching function. Below is an example code using [`axios`](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) and `.onPageInit`

```
myApp.onPageInit('show_project', function (page) {
    if (page.query != undefined && page.query.ctg != undefined){
      axios.get("/data/" + page.query.ctg + ".json")
      .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
      })
    }
})
```